# Entity Framework - Ambiguous DBContext constructors when instantiating a repostitory wrapper - using DbContext with a parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I running around in circles with this.

I am getting the following error when the solution tries to instantiate dbContext in a repository wrapper.

- ```
    InnerException  {"Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IDATARepositoryWrapper Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.DATARepositoryWrapper': Unable to activate type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:\r\nVoid .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext])\r\nVoid .ctor(JobsLedger.INTERFACES.IDbConnectionString)"} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
  ```

As it says there is ambiguity with two of the three dbcontext constructors.

Here are the constructors:

```
// Constructors..
// This is for the migration. OnConfiguring is setup to ignore both other constructors and go right through to
// base.(onConfiguring) without using the other constructor's parameters...
public DATAContext(DbContextOptions<DATAContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Here is my OnConfiguring method.

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (this.HttpContextAccessor != null)
        {
            var httpContext = this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var httpContextConnectionString = httpContext.Items["connectionString"].ToString();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(httpContextConnectionString ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
        }

        else
        {
            if (_connectionString != null)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString.ConnectionString ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
            }
        }

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
// This is for the creation of a new database as per NewDataBaseCreationService.
public DATAContext(IDbConnectionString connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString;
}

// This is when the account holder has logged in and the HttpContext has the connectionstring attached to as an item.
public DATAContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

..and here is where it falls down with that error above...

```
public class DATARepositoryWrapper: IDATARepositoryWrapper
{
    private readonly DATAContext _DATAContext;


    public DATARepositoryWrapper(DATAContext dataContext)
    {
        _DATAContext = dataContext;
    }
```

I would like to inject the DATAContext with the HttpContextAccessor..

How do I instantiate the wrapper with DbContext and a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject HttpContextAccessor using code below.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then you should use AddDbContext method override that takes service provider as input, which will help to get HttpContextAccessor object and access HttpContext to get connection string from Items.
If connectionstring is not available in Items then use default connectionstring.

```
services.AddDbContext<DATAContext>((serviceProvider, dbContextBuilder) =>
{
    var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    object connectionString = string.Empty;

    if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("connectionString", out connectionString))
    {
        dbContextBuilder.UseNpgsql((string)connectionString);
        return;
    }
    dbContextBuilder.UseNpgsql(defaultConnectionString);

}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

So now you will need only one constructor, that takes DbContextOptions as parameter.

```
public DATAContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
{}
```

Comment: Could you please review answer and mark it as answer if it resolves your question?